# Howto upload big files 2GB+ to .NET Core API controller from a form?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

While uploading a big file via Postman (from a frontend with form written in php I have the same issue) I am getting a 502 bad gateway error message back from the Azure Web App:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a
>   gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are
>   looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while
>   acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server,
>   it received an invalid response from the content server.

The error I see in Azure application insights:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException: The client
>   has disconnected <--- An operation was attempted on a nonexistent
>   network connection. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704CD)

This is happening while trying to upload a 2GB test file. With a 1GB file it is working fine but it needs to work up to ~5GB.

I have optimized the part which is writing the file streams to azure blob storage by using a block write approach (credits to: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/azure-blob-storage-part-4-uploading-large-blobs/) but for me it looks like that the connection is being closed to the client (to postman in this case) as this seems to be a single HTTP POST request and underlying Azure network stack (e.g. load balancer) is closing the connection as it takes to long until my API provides back the HTTP 200 OK for the HTTP POST request.

Is my assumption correct? If yes, how can achieve that the upload from my frontend (or postman) is happening in chunks (e.g. 15MB) which then can be acknowledged by the API in a faster way than the whole 2GB? Even creating a SAS URL for uploading to azure blob and returning the URL back to the browser would be fine but not sure how I can integrate that easily - also there are max block sizes afaik, so for a 2GB I would probably need to create multiple blocks. If this is the suggestion it would be great to get a good sample here BUT also other ideas are welcome!

This is the relevant part in my API controller endpoint in C# .Net Core 2.2:

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
            [HttpPost("DoPost")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> InsertFile([FromForm]List<IFormFile> files, [FromForm]string msgTxt)
            {
                 ...

                        // use generated container name
                        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(SqlInsertId);

                        // create container within blob
                        if (await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync())
                        {
                            await container.SetPermissionsAsync(
                                new BlobContainerPermissions
                                {
                                    // PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off
                                }
                                );
                        }

                        // loop through all files for upload
                        foreach (var asset in files)
                        {
                            if (asset.Length > 0)
                            {

                                // replace invalid chars in filename
                                CleanFileName = String.Empty;
                                CleanFileName = Utils.ReplaceInvalidChars(asset.FileName);

                                // get name and upload file
                                CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(CleanFileName);


                                // START of block write approach

                                //int blockSize = 256 * 1024; //256 kb
                                //int blockSize = 4096 * 1024; //4MB
                                int blockSize = 15360 * 1024; //15MB

                                using (Stream inputStream = asset.OpenReadStream())
                                {
                                    long fileSize = inputStream.Length;

                                    //block count is the number of blocks + 1 for the last one
                                    int blockCount = (int)((float)fileSize / (float)blockSize) + 1;

                                    //List of block ids; the blocks will be committed in the order of this list 
                                    List<string> blockIDs = new List<string>();

                                    //starting block number - 1
                                    int blockNumber = 0;

                                    try
                                    {
                                        int bytesRead = 0; //number of bytes read so far
                                        long bytesLeft = fileSize; //number of bytes left to read and upload

                                        //do until all of the bytes are uploaded
                                        while (bytesLeft > 0)
                                        {
                                            blockNumber++;
                                            int bytesToRead;
                                            if (bytesLeft >= blockSize)
                                            {
                                                //more than one block left, so put up another whole block
                                                bytesToRead = blockSize;
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                //less than one block left, read the rest of it
                                                bytesToRead = (int)bytesLeft;
                                            }

                                            //create a blockID from the block number, add it to the block ID list
                                            //the block ID is a base64 string
                                            string blockId =
                                              Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("BlockId{0}",
                                                blockNumber.ToString("0000000"))));
                                            blockIDs.Add(blockId);
                                            //set up new buffer with the right size, and read that many bytes into it 
                                            byte[] bytes = new byte[bytesToRead];
                                            inputStream.Read(bytes, 0, bytesToRead);

                                            //calculate the MD5 hash of the byte array
                                            string blockHash = Utils.GetMD5HashFromStream(bytes);

                                            //upload the block, provide the hash so Azure can verify it
                                            blockBlob.PutBlock(blockId, new MemoryStream(bytes), blockHash);

                                            //increment/decrement counters
                                            bytesRead += bytesToRead;
                                            bytesLeft -= bytesToRead;
                                        }

                                        //commit the blocks
                                        blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockIDs);

                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Exception thrown = {0}", ex);
                                        // return BadRequest(ex.StackTrace);
                                    }
                                }

                                // END of block write approach
...
```

And this is a sample HTTP POST via Postman:

[image: postman pic]

I set maxAllowedContentLength & requestTimeout in web.config for testing already:

> requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295"

and

> aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
>   stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout"
>   requestTimeout="00:59:59" hostingModel="InProcess"

Comment: Apart from extending the timeout and maxContentLength or using `HttpPostedFileBase` as a model, you could just split the file into `chunks` with JavaScript on the client side. Then send lots of small chunks a 100 MB.

Comment: For upload large files, one suggestion is that you can try [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement).

Comment: I think I read it's a bad idea to use IFormFile for big files as it loads it to memory.

Comment: @Charles thank you. Will HttpPostedFileBase change anything? Any sample for sending in chunks with JavaScript on the client side?

Comment: @IvanYang thanks, would using DataMovement.TransferManager change the behaviour how the file is being uploaded from client -> API? Because from API to Azure blob storage I think that the current biuffered block write approach is working fine now.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/shiawuen/1534477 check this out, its pretty easy. On the server side you just save all the parts and merge them together, its just byte[] arrays.

Comment: @Charles is this approach compatible with the block write approach we are using to write from api to azure blob storage or do I need to merge the chunks of the whole file before I write to azure? I need an approach where I don’t need to load the whole file to memory. 

The solution I need should look like this: client sends chunk -> api takes one or more chunks into a buffer (not the whole file) and writes to azure blob storage in blocks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to upload a large blob file to Azure storage, get an SAS token from your backend and upload this file from client-side directly will be a better soultion I think as it will not add your backend workload . You can use code below to get a SAS token with write permission for 2 hours only for your client :

```
    var containerName = "<container name>";
    var accountName = "<storage account name>";
    var key = "<storage account key>";
    var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, key);
    var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred,true);
    var container = account.CreateCloudBlobClient().GetContainerReference(containerName);

    var writeOnlyPolicy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy() { 
        SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.Now,
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2),
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Write
    };

    var sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(writeOnlyPolicy);
```

After you get this sas token, you can use it to upload files by [storage JS SDK](https://aka.ms/downloadazurestoragejsblob) on your client-side. This is a html sample :

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title> 
        upload demo
    </title> 

    <script src= 
"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
    </script> 


    <script src= "./azure-storage-blob.min.js"> </script> 
</head> 

<body> 
    <div align="center"> 
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data"
                id="myform"> 

            <div > 
                <input type="file" id="file" name="file" /> 
                <input type="button" class="button" value="Upload"
                        id="but_upload"> 
            </div> 
        </form> 
        <div id="status"></div>


    </div>   

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() { 


            var sasToken = '?sv=2018-11-09&sr=c&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXOuqHSrH0Fo%3D&st=2020-01-27T03%3A58%3A20Z&se=2020-01-28T03%3A58%3A20Z&sp=w'
            var containerURL = 'https://stanstroage.blob.core.windows.net/container1/'


            $("#but_upload").click(function() { 

                var file = $('#file')[0].files[0]; 
                const container = new azblob.ContainerURL(containerURL + sasToken, azblob.StorageURL.newPipeline(new azblob.AnonymousCredential));
                try {
                    $("#status").wrapInner("uploading .... pls wait");


                    const blockBlobURL = azblob.BlockBlobURL.fromContainerURL(container, file.name);
                    var result  = azblob.uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(
                            azblob.Aborter.none, file, blockBlobURL);

                    result.then(function(result) {
                        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Done"
                        }, function(err) {
                            document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Error"
                            console.log(err); 
                        });


                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }


            });
        }); 
    </script> 
</body> 

</html>
```

I uploaded a 3.6GB .zip file for 20 mins and it works perfectly for me, sdk will open mutiple threads and upload your large file part by part: 
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Note: in this case ,pls make sure you have enabled CORS for your storage account  so that statc html could post requests to Azure storage service.**

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is a great example. In this case you are creating a SAS token for a container. Would it also work like this? I know the file names before. So I can create a container but the SAS tokens I would create only for the file blobs and return the list back to the client. Based on this list and the html/js sample the client could loop through this list and upload the files to the corresponding blobs?

Comment: Hi @Romeosan, yes , I think that is realizable